# Triple Component - pass data from picker to another view page text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a triple component picker that I am trying to send the info to another view into text fields.  I have it set up right now to go to an alert.  If anyone has code or the know how to send the data from the triple component picker to another view please let me know.  i have been trying for weeks now..and have had no answers that help.  thanks in advance (a noobie) haha

```
#import  
#define kOneComponent 0 
#define kTwoComponent 1 
#define kThreeComponent 2 
interface FirstViewController : UIViewController UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource 
{ IBOutlet UIPickerView *doublePicker; 
NSArray *oneTypes; 
NSArray *twoTypes; 
NSArray *threeTypes; } 
property (nonatomic,retain) UIPickerView *doublePicker; 
property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *oneTypes; 
property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *twoTypes; property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *threeTypes; 

-(IBAction)buttonPressed; 

end
```

Comment: Vanya,  I really appreciate your help in this....I have tried to fit the code in every which way I can think of, and can't get it working.... if anyone has an email address I can send them the xcode project (it is really small) and show me where to plug in the code and set it up to receive on the next page... drinks on me! haha.

Comment: I wish to help you more, but since your style of coding is totally different than mine, I cannot. I don't use IB (it's black box for some cases) at all and other things, sorry.

Comment: could you email me an example working xcode of how you pass code from picker to another view in your style... would be greatly appreciated.... lawrenceschoen@hotmail.com

Comment: dont worry, and thanks again for the help.. i cracked it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will get you some idea!

```
// First component
int selected_1 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *str_1 = [firstComponentValueArray objectAtIndex:selected_1];

// Second component
int selected_2 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];
NSString *str_2 = [secondComponentValueArray objectAtIndex:selected_2];

// Third component
int selected_3 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2];
NSString *str_3 = [thirdComponentValueArray objectAtIndex:selected_3];

// Do what you want with these values and pass it to a view
```

Comment: where would I insert this? Do you have email I could send the xcode project to, and maybe help me fill it in, or show me where... I am going crazzzzzyyy with this hahahah

Comment: You can add these lines at the time you need to pass the value to a view.

Comment: This is my firstView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define kOneComponent  0
#define kTwoComponent  1
#define kThreeComponent 2



interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *doublePicker;
    NSArray *oneTypes;
    NSArray *twoTypes;
    NSArray *threeTypes;
    
}

property (nonatomic,retain)  UIPickerView *doublePicker;
property (nonatomic,retain)  NSArray *oneTypes;
property (nonatomic,retain)  NSArray *twoTypes;
property (nonatomic,retain)  NSArray *threeTypes;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed;

end

Comment: I also have the @ in there, but for some reason I can't post them... what would I add in this firstView.h file (this is the main one with the picker, I am wanting to send it to SecondViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPicker delegate method

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

If the another view is done separately as controller you will need to set properties, which represents text fields of this class in the above method.

Comment: where would I insert this? Do you have email I could send the xcode project to, and maybe help me fill it in, or show me where... I am going crazzzzzyyy with this hahahah

Comment: It is not that difficult as u probably think. The only condition to make it work is to define delegation in the class where you have allocated your UIPIckerView could be done like this "@interface presetPicker: UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDelegate>{}" and then in the same class implement mentioned method

Comment: This is my firstView.h #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> #define kOneComponent 0 #define kTwoComponent 1 #define kThreeComponent 2 interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> { IBOutlet UIPickerView *doublePicker; NSArray *oneTypes; NSArray *twoTypes; NSArray *threeTypes; } property (nonatomic,retain) UIPickerView *doublePicker; property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *oneTypes; property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *twoTypes; property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *threeTypes; -(IBAction)buttonPressed; end

Comment: I also have the @ in there, but for some reason I can't post them... what would I add in this firstView.h file (this is the main one with the picker, I am wanting to send it to SecondViewController

Comment: This is my FirstViewController.m

Comment: #import "FirstViewController.h"


implementation FirstViewController

synthesize doublePicker;
synthesize oneTypes;
synthesize twoTypes;
synthesize threeTypes;

// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self == [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: -(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    NSInteger oneRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                        kOneComponent];
 NSInteger twoRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                        kTwoComponent];
 NSInteger threeRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:
                          kThreeComponent];

Comment: kThreeComponent];
    NSString *one = [oneTypes objectAtIndex:oneRow];
 NSString *two = [twoTypes objectAtIndex:twoRow];
 NSString *three = [threeTypes objectAtIndex:threeRow];
 
 NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                         @"Last = %@                                           2nd Last = %@                                             3rd Last = %@",one, two, three];

Comment: UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous 3" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
 [message release];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    
    NSArray *oneArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

Comment: @"90",@"91",@"92"self.oneTypes = oneArray;
 [oneArray release];
    
 NSArray *twoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"90",@"91",@"92" self.twoTypes = twoArray;
 [twoArray release];
 
 NSArray *threeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"90",@"91",@"92"self.threeTypes = threeArray;
 [threeArray release];
 [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: - (void)dealloc {
 [doublePicker release];
    [oneTypes release];
 [twoTypes release];
 [threeTypes release];
    [super dealloc];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
 return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 60;
    
    if (component == kOneComponent)
        return[self.oneTypes count];
    return[self.twoTypes count];
    return[self.threeTypes count];

Comment: if (component == kTwoComponent)
        return[self.oneTypes count];
    return[self.twoTypes count];
    return[self.threeTypes count];
    
    if (component == kThreeComponent)
        return[self.oneTypes count];
    return[self.twoTypes count];
    return[self.threeTypes count];

Comment: }

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
 if (component == kThreeComponent)
        return [self. threeTypes objectAtIndex:row];
 return [self. twoTypes objectAtIndex:row];
 return [self. oneTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    
}



@end